# laptop enery management for improving battery lifetime Linux

Tags: linux, battery

I have bought a Lenovo Ideapad that cames with Windows preinstalled. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 to dual boot. There is a tool for Windows called Lenovo Energy Manager that allows to control the charge of your battery, I mean, I can configure it so that when my computer is connected to AC and the charge is 60%, the computer takes all the energy from the AC and not from the battery. Doing this the battery lifetime is longer. Do you know some software similar for Ubuntu?

Comment: any modern laptop would use AC for power supply when plugged on AC and battery when not plugged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no true solution regarding this because Lenovo has not yet created anything like TVSU for linux. But there has been an interesting forum post regarding this particular post : [Forum Link](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Think-Innovation/Linux-battery-battery-battery/m-p/330519)

Hope this clarifies something for you!

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but it is possible to do this - especially with lenovos. See:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity

From Ubuntu but works for all lenovos, just need the tp_smpai kernel module. Other brands have similar things.

Comment: This only works for the Lenovo ThinkPad range, not the IdeaPad range which the questioner mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick for conservation mode in linux!
first boot to Windows. Connect AC cable and turn on conservation mode in lenovo energy manager and wait until the charging stops(about 60 percent). Now restart system and boot to linux and enjoy...
This solution works for me in lenovo ideaPad Z-510 and ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Even if you turn off the system, until you disconnect the cable, this feature will remain active

Comment: Instead of adding information in comment, please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/264728/edit) your answer.

Answer (score 0):

in Ubuntu 20.04 and above the Kernel can access the acpi calls.

There is a Gnome extention that has a GUI for this and also acts as an indicator, I tried it on Ubuntu 20.04 and works fine.[click here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4129/charging-mode/)

there is also a manual method from the terminal

first

```
sudo su
```

reading the current status:

```
cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

enable Conservation mode:

```
echo 1  >  /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

disable conservation mode:

```
echo 0  > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

Answer (score 0):

A direct and simple solution to your problem would be this:

1. Check if Ideapad_laptop kernel module is loaded (You don't need to repeat this)

   ```
   lsmod | grep ideapad_laptop
   ```
2. To know the current status of conservation mode:

   (If Output is 1 - conservation mode ON, 0 - conservation mode OFF)

   ```
   cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
   ```

   (You may have different name for "VPC2004:00" so check that by going to the folder "ideapad-acpi" by `cd` command and running `ls` there)
3. Use following command to turn on/off the conservation mode : (1 - conservation ON, 0 -conservation OFF)

   ```
   echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
   echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
   ```